# Regular Expression get value between < >

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Been trying for a while now but can't seem to get it correctly with RE in python.

I have this as return

```
Kinepolis Ticket <info@domain.com>
```

however I would like to store the name and email in seperate variables. So the result would be:

```
name = Kinepolis Ticket  
email = info@domain.com
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
import re
string = "Kinepolis Ticket <info@domain.com>"

rx = re.compile(r'([^<>]+)\s<([^<>]+)>')
m = rx.search(string)
if m:
    name, email = m.groups()
    print(name, email)
```

---

Or - as of `Python 3.8`:

```
import re
string = "Kinepolis Ticket <info@domain.com>"

if (m := re.search(r'([^<>]+)\s<([^<>]+)>', string)):
    # ^^^ walrus
    name, email = m.groups()
    print(name, email)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.match('([^<>]*)<([^<>]*)>','Kinepolis Ticket <info@domain.com>')
>>> name = m.group(1).strip()
>>> email = m.group(2).strip()
>>> print("name={},email={}".format(name,email))
name=Kinepolis Ticket,email=info@domain.com
```